# Chrome storage sync set and get not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension to make my job easier, but I am having a problem with my code. The problem I am getting is I am trying to pass in a variable to chrome.storage.sync.set but I don't think it is registering quite like it needs to because it always displays undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Check if output is not empty
    if(output.innerHTML != ""){
        //Onclick function
        $("a").click(function() {
            //Get id of element and pass into clickedElemID
            var clickedElemID = $(this).attr('id');
            //Run handler functin
            handler(clickedElemID);
        });
    }
    //If empty, set innerHTML to No Selection Found
    else{
        output.innerHTML = "No selection found";
    }
});

function handler(elem){
    //Get innerHTML of element and pass into output
    var output = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
    //Set sync storage for specified element id and store output
    chrome.storage.sync.set({[elem]: output}, function() {
        //Annonymous function as follows:
        //Get sync storage for same element
        chrome.storage.sync.get(elem, function(data) {
            document.getElementById(elem).nextElementSibling.classList.remove('na');
            document.getElementById(elem).nextElementSibling.classList.add('tx4');
            document.getElementById(elem).nextElementSibling.innerHTML = data.elem;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It should be `data[elem]` in the last line. Also why do you read the data right after writing it? It makes no sense.

Comment: Unless you need to reference the values outside the handler scope, just set a local variable for readability.